# Android WebView Loads all the urls but not only mine

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load my site in android web view, whenever I set url to google.com or any other it loads without any problem but when I try to load my site darpankulkarni.in then it just shows blank screen.

WebViewActivity:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    {

        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    }

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.darpankulkarni.in");
    //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
}
}
```

MyWebViewClient:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override

// show the web page in webview but not in web browser
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    //webProg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by adding code below settings to the web view inside of onCreate

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{

    websettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    websettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    websettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    websettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

}
```

Apply the basic settings to your web view for loading the  web view in view port

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

So Here is the complete working code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    {
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }

    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

ProgressDialog  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)    {              
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading the Web View");
            progressDialog.show();

        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }); 

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.darpankulkarni.in");
    //  mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    //  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

}
```

Don't forget to give the  internet permission in your manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I created a progress dialog for loading the web view as it taking some time to load.

Hope this vll help !!